# ReactJS - Triggering function in another component

Tags: reactjs

I have two components in my app they are listed below.

Question is: How can I trigger that `resetTime()` function (it's in first component) from second component with button `SAVE TIME` ?

Now with `SAVE TIME` button I call Function `tuplahomma()` which is saving time to localstorage, and reseting input value field.

Point for this is reset time when saving results.

[image: Stopwatch app]

First component:

```
class SecondTimer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    

    // Start funktio määrittää running arvon -> true, joka kertoo sen, että kello käy. Tallentaa tänne ajan, josta SeconTimerNumber hakee tiedon
    this.state = {
      running: false, // Alustettu falseksi, eli ohjelman avatessa kello ei käy
      currentTimeMs: 0,
      currentTimeSec: 0,
      currentTimeMin: 0,
    };
  }

  resetTime = () => {
    this.setState({
      currentTimeMs: 0,
      currentTimeSec: 0,
      currentTimeMin: 0,
    });
  };
```

Second component have a button `SAVE TIME`, which i want to trigger that `resetTime()` function in first component.

```
  saveTime = () => {
    if (typeof Storage !== 'undefined') {
      this.saveToLocalStorage();
  
    } else {
      console.error('local storage not supported');
    }
    this.setHistoryState();
  };


  reset = () => { 
    this.setState({value: ""});
  };


  tuplahomma = () => {
    this.saveTime();
    this.reset();

  }   


  render() {
    return (
      
      <div className={'sekuntikello-list'}>
        <div className="container">
          <form id="title-value" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} 
                disabled = "true">
            <label>
              <Form.Control className={'input-field'} placeholder="Title" type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} /></label>
          </form>
        </div>
        
        <div className={'save-reset-napit-div'}>
          
          <Button className={"save-reset-nappi"} variant="success" size="lg" onClick={this.tuplahomma}>SAVE TIME</Button>
          <Button className={"save-reset-nappi"} variant="danger" size="lg" onClick={this.resetTime}>RESET HISTORY</Button>
        </div>
        <h3>LAPS</h3>
        <div className={'tulostaulu-main'}>
          <div className={'tulostaulu'}>
            <ul>
              {this.state.history.map((item, index) => <li key={index}>{item}</li>)}
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**RIGHT SOLUTION:**

First component, I added this `clickResetTime={this.resetTime}` to where I rendering second component for other things:

```
<div className={'right'}>
    <SecondTimerList
        clickResetTime={this.resetTime} // Added this one
        {...this.state}
        formatTime={this.formatTime}
    />
 </div>
```

And I added this `clickResetTime` to second component's function `tuplahomma()` like this:

```
tuplahomma = () => {
    this.saveTime();
    this.reset();
    this.props.clickResetTime(); // This one
  }
```

Comment: Are the 2 components connected? Does one create the other or have a common parent?

Comment: @DanielSindrestean Just normal export/import.

Comment: but which component imports the other? I would like to see the exact piece of code where one component uses the other, or a parent component uses both

Comment: @DanielSindrestean I'll edit original post in one hour to show how it works now. Just wait couple of minutes :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Passing Down Functions As Props**

FirstComponent.js

```
class FirstComponent extends React.Component {

  constructor(){
    super()
   
    this.state = {
      running: false, 
      currentTimeMs: 0,
      currentTimeSec: 0,
      currentTimeMin: 0,
    };

  }

  resetTime = () => {
    this.setState({
      currentTimeMs: 0,
      currentTimeSec: 0,
      currentTimeMin: 0,
    });
  };


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <SecondComponent clickResetTime={this.resetTime} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default FirstComponent;
```

SecondComponent.js

```
class SecondComponent extends React.Component {

    …

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                …
          <Button className={"save-reset-nappi"} variant="danger" size="lg" onClick={this.props.clickResetTime()}>SAVE TIME</Button>
                …
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default SecondComponent;
```

Comment: that will trigger on the first render, fyi should be this.props.clickResetTime

Comment: I added this `<SecondComponent clickResetTime={this.resetTime}` to my first component, where i importing other things from that component. And added this `this.props.clickResetTime()` to function `tuplahomma()`. Now it works. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean call two functions when 'SAVE TIME' is clicked?

```
 <Button className={"save-reset-nappi"} variant="success" size="lg" onClick={() => {
      this.props.tuplahomma();
      this.props.resetTime();
    }}>SAVE TIME</Button>
```

Comment: Thank for your answer. Now i call two functions that is not problem. Problem is call third function from another component `(resetTime()` from first component.